# Android HttpPost.setEntity() equivalent in retrofit

Tags: rest, retrofit

I am trying to implement retrofit to an earlier project that used that used classes from org.apache package.

earlier i had a code like this

```
url.addParameters(url,param); // add query parameters
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(payload); //InputStreamEntity payload passed as argument
```

now while converting to retrofit i declared following

```
@POST ("/x")
CustomClass custom(

    @Query("ctid") String ctid,
    @Body HttpEntity payload
);
```

However this gives a stackoverflow error which i suspect because

```
@Body HttpEntity payload
```

is not an equivalent to

```
HttpPost.setEntity(HttpEntity);
```

what would be the correct call in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Retrofit the `@Body` can either be any class which can be serialized by the `Converter` used when initializing your `RestAdapter` or with `TypedOutput`.

Usually if you're dealing with JSON you'd simply create POJO classes which would be automatically serialize to JSON by Retrofit.  By if you're not dealing with JSON and perhaps trying to merge the gaps between 2 library like in your case, you could wrap your `InputStreamEntity` it into your own implementation of `TypedOutput`.

Here's a small example.

```
// JSON here is merely used for content, as mentioned use serialization if your content is JSON
String body = "{\"firstname\": \"Parth\", \"lastname\": \"Srivastav\"}";
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));

// Here is your HttpEntity, I've simply created it from a String for demo purposes.
HttpEntity httpEntity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream, inputStream.available(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

// Create your own implementation of TypedOutput
TypedOutput payload = new TypedOutput() {
    @Override
    public String fileName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String mimeType() {
        return httpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long length() {
        return httpEntity.getContentLength();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        httpEntity.writeTo(out);
    }
};
```

Then define your Interface like so

```
@POST ("/x")
CustomClass custom(
    @Query("ctid") String ctid,
    @Body TypedOutput payload
);
```

And execute it like so using the `payload` object from above.

```
api.custom("1", payload);
```

---

But as mentioned if you're actually working with JSON then here's a quick example of how to setup your code.

Let's say you'd want a JSON body of

```
{
    "firstname": "Parth",
    "lastname": "Srivastav"
}
```

you would create a Java class which you could call User let say

```
public class User {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;

    public User(String firstname; String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

Modify your interface like so

```
@POST ("/x")
CustomClass custom(
    @Query("ctid") String ctid,
    @Body User payload
);
```

And use it like this

```
api.custom("1", new User("Parth", "Srivastav"));
```

Comment: This is all correct, but a better way to get that JSON output is to make a class with two fields and let Gson serialize it for you.

Comment: @JakeWharton is correct, I've updated my post to be a bit clearer about this.

Answer (score 1):

in retrofit2 here is the solution:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = {you jsonObject} //change the json to requestBody
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),(jsonObject).toString());
```

in the post method,just use @Body,here is an example:

```
Call<Response> getHostList(@Body RequestBody  entery);
```